# ionic load different part when user logged-in

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a ionic project which starts a user-intro page. I'll go to **Main** page after click **start** button.

**app.js:**

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic',
    'app.intro'
])
```

**app/intro/intro.js:**

```
angular.module('app.intro',['app.intro.controller'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('intro', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/intro/index.html',
        controller: 'IntroCtrl'
    })
    .state('main', {
          url: '/main',
          templateUrl: 'app/main/index.html'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

**IntroCtrl (app/intro/controller.js):**

```
angular.module('app.intro.controller',[])
    .controller('IntroCtrl',function($scope,$state,$ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {

        $scope.startMain = function() {
            $state.go('main');
        };
    });
```

But if the user is not logged-in I want to show login page instead.What should I do? Sorry, I'm new to ionic and angular. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about the default state's controller simply using $state.go to one state if you are logged in and another if you are not?